# How to use a series of commands on vim

Tags: vim, sort, uniq

Hi guys in the terminal I use the command `cat file.txt | sort | uniq -c` . First I would like to use that command on vim and save the output to another file without the output being print when I run the program . Thank you.

Comment: Is your goal just to have the output of that command stored in a file?  If you want to edit it, couldn't you do it after creating that file?

Comment: `sort file.txt | uniq -c > my_new_file` should do what you want - if not, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `read` to read the output of a command:

`:read !sort file.txt | uniq -c`

(`!` means this is shell command)

Which would read the output of the command and insert it after the cursor, then you could save it as a file. But you could also do this (as @Panki mentioned):

`sort file.txt | uniq -c > new_file.txt`

Which would do what you want, but skip the vim part.

Also, "cating" to sort or grep is useless, sort or grep don't rewrite files, they just produce a output based on the input i.e. content of a file. If you need to grep something out of a file you can use `grep find_this in_this_file.txt`